# Editting from an existing Excel file deletes its data

Tags: java, apache-poi

Why do the worksheets in my Excel workbook get deleted whenever I write to/edit it through FileOutStream?

Code:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook;
FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

String excelFileName = util.getFile(FileExtension.XLS); // Here is a method I wrote in a utility class I made, that asks if they want to create a new file or select an existing one.
// This works. And it returns the location of the file created/selected.

fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
getAllSheetsFromWB(workbook);

workbook.write(fileOut);
workbook.close();
fileOut.close();
```

Here, I'm trying to get all the sheets so I can determine if there are any existing sheets on the workbook:

```
private String[] getAllSheetsFromWB(HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    int numSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
    String[] result = new String[numSheets];

    result = new String[numSheets];

    if(numSheets > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numSheets; i++) {
            result[i] = workbook.getSheetAt(i).getSheetName(); 
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Doing this removes the sheets on an existing workbook.

UPDATE: This is because I never used the FileInputStream to read the file. See below for solution.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
FileInputStream fileIn = null;

fileIn = new FileInputStream((new File(excelFileName));
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileIn);

//do stuff to workbook here

fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);

workbook.write(fileOut);
workbook.close();
fileIn.close();
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: This depends on the library you're using to work with the excel files. In POI, this is relatively easy.

Comment: I'm using Apache POI. If I create a new one, will I have to close it before writing to it?

Comment: In POI, you just pass an OutputStream and it will rewrite the workbook in that stream, regardless if it's a new file or not.

Comment: You better first start reading and coding some then we help if you are stuck https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html

Comment: Every time I do this, it removes all the sheets that already exist. When I open the Excel file, it says that data was removed.

Comment: Show us your code...

Comment: Please provide the relevant code to reproduce the error.

Comment: No your getAllSheetsFromWB is not the problem, you have never loaded the excel file... you are creating a new HSSFWorkbook() and then writing it to the name that you have selected (this new is empty!!)

Comment: Is this the reason why I get the "File error: data may have been lost." on the Excel file when I open it? How do I fix this?

Comment: I posted an answer, if you need more help let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the `getAllSheetsFromWB`, instead its that you have never read the excel file.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(excelFileName);

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
```

hence before you where creating a `new HSSFWorkbook()` and writing this empty workbook to your file `workbook.write(fileOut);`

Naturally you should also do some `try catch` and `close` the stream

For more info check out this  [java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: My pleasure, consider accepting the answer and closing the question, have fun